In a superconducting LC circuit, is some energy dissipated in the creation and destruction of the magnetic or electric fields?
Quite simply, I'm imagining a pure LC circuit with zero resistance, current oscillating positive and negative, energy oscillating between the capacitor E-field and the inductor magnetic field. Is energy dissipated in the creation and destruction of these fields? Does it matter (for energy dissipation) whether the fields penetrate vacuum vs matter (and further, whether that matter is para- dia- or ferro- magnetic)?
To clarify, I'm trying to understand whether there's some energy dissipation associated with the realignment of the magnetic or electric moments of the atoms in the material the fields penetrate.

Yes, some energy is dissipated in superconducting resonating cavities; it isn't much, but there's entropy associated with nulling the supercurrent and then reestablishing it.   It's not exactly a changing field inside the superconducting material (because the changing B field is excluded).
The measure of the loss per cycle is tricky, because you can't
trust a probe not to be the dominant loss element.    This paper says it's parts per trillion.

No the capacitor and the inductor STORE energy.One absorbs energy in one cycle of the oscillation and the other releases energy in the same cycle.

Sure, I understand the fields themselves store and give back the energy, are you saying there's also no energy dissipation in re-aligning the magnetic or electric moments of the atoms in the material the fields penetrate?
